# Bash: using the output of one command in the other

Tags: bash, svn, jira

I have the following requirement here: Fetch all the commits from our SVN from the last two years and list the title of all the JIRA issues that had code committed. Our commit rules are pretty strict, so a commit must start with the JIRA code, like: `COR-3123 Fixed the bug, introduced a new one`

So, I wrote the following shell script to get this working:

`svn log -r{2012-04-01}:{2014-04-01} | grep "COR-" | cut -f1 -d" " | sort -u`

This gets me all the JIRA codes.

But now I want to use these in the following command:

`wget --quiet  --load-cookies cookies.txt -O - http://jira.example.com/browse/{HERE} | sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'`

Ie: get the JIRA page via wget and parse out the title... (I have already cached my login credentials to use with wget in cookies.txt)

and obviously to the location `{HERE}` I want to insert the code obtained from the first list. Doing this via a two step (step 1: get list, step 2 iterate via list) script (python, perl, ... ) is not a problem, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it in ONE step, using bash :)
(Yes, I know there is JIRA rest API)

Comment: `xargs -I {} wget http://jira.example.com/browse/{}`

Comment: @RolandJansen That's amazing. Please put it in an answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to pass the parameter to `wget`:

```
xargs -I {} wget http://jira.example.com/browse/{}
```